# Increase blob size over 64 kb in node.js formData

Tags: node.js, max, blob

: )

I want to upload a local PDF file via an API. The problem I am stuck with is that files are uploaded with a maximum size of 64 kb. Anything above that throws an error. ArrayBuffer exceed.

I know that the Blob function only allows a maximum of 64 kb. However, I cannot find any other way. All attempts have failed so far...

This is my reduced code:

```
let path = `/api/v1/projects/{idOfFolder}/files`;
let url = `https://${header.hostname}${path}`;

// Send binary data
        const rawData = readFileSync(localFilepath);
        console.log(`File size: ${rawData.length}`);
         const binary = new Blob([rawData], {
                     type: 'application/pdf'
         });

        const form = new FormData();
        form.set("type", "DOCUMENT");
        form.set("data", binary, "filename.pdf");

// Add the file
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'X-CN-API-Key': secretKey
            },
            body: form
        });

        // Read the response result
        let interimResult = JSON.parse(await response.text());
        console.log(interimResult);
```

From Swagger documentation (API):

> {
> type* string
> File type ('FOLDER', 'DOCUMENT', 'IMAGE')
>
> folderId  string
> Folder ID of the file
>
> data  string($binary)
> Content data (required if type is not FOLDER)
>
> name  string
> Name of the file (or folder) to create. If omitted the file name will be used. Required if type 'FOLDER'
> }

I hope, someone can help? Is there another way than blob or do I have to add something? I am searching for days to solve this. I've already quitted and want to try my luck here.

Tried ArrayBuffer, tried Buffer.from ... but maybe I am not into it.

Thank you very much
Klaudia